# Why is my check box control always unchecked (false)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to create a check box control with the code behind and there was a button to show the status (either `true` or `false`) of that check box when clicked, but the problem was that the check box was always unchecked (`false`).

Can anyone figure this out? Thanks!

I need to keep the `loadCheckBox()` in the `Button` click event in order to do some stuffs.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) loadCheckBox();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(chkBox.Checked); // <<< always shows "False"
        loadCheckBox();
    }

    public void loadCheckBox()
    {
        Table1.Rows.Clear();

        var tRow = new TableRow();
        var cell = new TableCell();

        cell.Controls.Add(chkBox);
        tRow.Cells.Add(cell);
        Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `loadCheckBox()` outside of `if (!IsPostBack)` and remove `loadCheckBox()` from `Button1_Click`. Dynamically added controls need to be added on every page load. In your situation the CheckBox does not exist on PostBack and therefore it is false.

Comment: This simple adds a new check box every time there is post back is occurred, erasing the existing checkbox along with its value.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a post back is sent, a **new** instance of `Default` page is created, and so does `chkBox`. This is why it is never checked.

In the `Button1_Click` handler, you want to get the first cell of last row of `Table1` and read its `Checked` property.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea, but it didn't work. I tried to get the control in the cell and it gave the same result. Here is my code in Buttin1_Click()

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            TableRowCollection rows = Table1.Rows;

            foreach(TableRow row in rows)
            {
                TableCellCollection cells = row.Cells;

                foreach(TableCell cell in cells)
                {
                    var controls = cell.Controls;

                    foreach(CheckBox chk in controls)
                    {
                        Response.Write(chk.Checked);
                    }
                }
            }
        }